# Issue Symfony 3.4 "object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have an issue with "object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation" on Symfony 3.4 when I try to delete selected items of table. I think it's an issue when I try to get the "spectacle" with the id ("findOneBy()")

This is my code (html.twig) :

```
<form method="delete" action="{{ path('admin_spectacle_delete_selected') }}">
<button class="content-red btn btn-fabop" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Tout supprimer</button>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="all"></th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Lieu</th>
                <th>Date spectacle</th>
                <th>Annee</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for spectacle in spectacles %}
            <tr>
                <td id="spectacle{{ spectacle.id }}"><input type="checkbox" name='multiSelected[]' value="{{ spectacle.id }}"></td>
                <td>{{ spectacle.nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ spectacle.lieu }}</td>
                <td>{{ spectacle.dateSpectacle }}</td>
                <td>{{ spectacle.annee }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="content-blue btn-fabop btn" href="{{ path('admin_spectacle_show', { 'id': spectacle.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Détail</a>
                    <a class="content-purple btn-fabop btn" href="{{ path('admin_spectacle_edit', { 'id': spectacle.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edition</a>
                    <a class="content-red btn-fabop btn" href="{{ path('admin_spectacle_delete_confirmed', { 'id': spectacle.id }) }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Suppression</a>


                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and controller :

```
  /**
* Confirmation delete
*
* @Route("/deleteSelected", name="admin_spectacle_delete_selected")
*/
public function deleteSelectedAction(Request $request)
{

    $items_selected_id = $request->get('multiSelected');

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $repository = $em->getRepository(Spectacle::class);
      foreach($items_selected_id as $item_id) {

        $spectacle = $repository->findOneById($item_id);

        if (!$spectacle) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No spectacle found for id '.$spectacle
            );
        }
        else{
            $em->remove($spectacle);
        }
      }
      $em->flush();  
      return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_spectacle_index');
}
```

Thank you for your response !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from there:

```
<form method="delete" action="admin_spectacle_delete_selected">
```

You're litterally calling `.../admin_spectacle_delete_selected`, i assume you must have a route `/spectacle/{id}`

So you're matching another route trying to get a "spectacle" whose id is "admin_spectacle_delete_selected"

Your form should look like this:

```
<form method="delete" action="{{ path('admin_spectacle_delete_selected') }}">
```

Which would match your deleteSelectedAction

Also your Action should look like something like this

```
  $items_selected_id = $request->get('multiSelected');

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $repository = $em->getRepository(Spectacle::class)
  foreach($items_selected_id as $item_id) {

    $spectacle = $repository->findOneById($item_id);

    if (!$spectacle) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No spectacle found for id '.$spectacle
        );
    }
    else{
        $em->remove($spectacle);
    }
  }
  $em->flush();  
  return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_spectacle_index');
```

You are redeclaring your EntityManager / Flushing each loop which doesn't make much sense to me :).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try your code but when i click on button "Tout supprimer" I have the same exception : "NotFoundHttpException HTTP 404 Not Found FabopBundle\Entity\Spectacle object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation".

Comment: In fact, I try to remove selected items in datatables and multiselect get the items selected or not

Comment: So, i can't use id in path of controller because I want to remove just the items selected. I don't know if I'm clear

Comment: Oopsssssssss I didn't see my bad

Comment: I don't kwow what is the issue. Do you think it's due to Param Converter ?

Comment: Can you update your post with your changed code ? 
The attribute action in your form is incorrect for sure :)

Comment: I updated it you can see my code. In any case, thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Yes i just seen ... It's ok now

Comment: In fact, i think that I'm not reaching deleteSelectedAction since the begining. Yes the same error...

Comment: It's still the same exception and i have clear the cache and i don't see the url in html....

Comment: I have leave my computer but i still logged. I can't test for now but i will as soon as possible

Comment: Hello, I don't know if you are here but the exception is always the same.... There isn't any view with controller's route, maybe it's due to that ....

Comment: In fact, I don't see the url so i have to add a associated view ? I see the url issue but i forgot to tell you ...

Comment: The issue is resolved. I just replace the delete method to post in my form action and that's work ! Thank you for your answers !